# Android Programming SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

After clicking submit button, a massage arises: *unfortunately SQLite_demo has stop working*. And one more thing that when the project first displayed on emulator a toast shows a pop up : *constructor called*. Please explain why.

Here is my code:

**RahulDatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class RahulDatabaseHelper{
RahulHelper RH;
public RahulDatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
   RH=new RahulHelper(context);
}
public long insertData(String username,String userpassword)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=RH.getWritableDatabase();**strong text**
    ContentValues Values=new ContentValues();
    Values.put(RahulHelper.NAME,username);
    Values.put(RahulHelper.PASSWORD,userpassword);
    long id=sqLiteDatabase.insert(RahulHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,Values);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return id;
}


static class RahulHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final  String DATABASE_NAME="vivzdatabase.db";
    private static final  String TABLE_NAME="VIVZTABLE";
    private static final  String UID="_id";
    private static final  String NAME="Name";
    private static final  String PASSWORD="Password";
    private static final  int DATABASE_VERSION=4;
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE ="create table" +TABLE_NAME+ "("+UID+ "integer primary key autoincrement, "
            +NAME+ "VARCHAR(255)"+PASSWORD+"VARCHAR(255));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME;

    Context context;
    RahulHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
        Message.mess(context,"Constructor called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            Message.mess(context,"onCreate called");
        }catch (SQLException e)
        {Message.mess(context,""+e);}

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        try {
            Message.mess(context,"onUpgrade called");
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }catch (SQLException e)
        {Message.mess(context,""+e);}
    }
}}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText et1,et2;
RahulDatabaseHelper rahulDatabaseHelper;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userpass);

    rahulDatabaseHelper=new RahulDatabaseHelper(this);

 }

public void method(View v)
{
  String name=et1.getText().toString();
    String pass=et2.getText().toString();

    long id=rahulDatabaseHelper.insertData(name,pass);
    if (id<0)
        Message.mess(this,"UnSuccessFull");
    else
        Message.mess(this,"Row Inserted SuccessFully");

}}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Enter Name"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="enter usr name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Enter Password"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userpass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:onClick="method"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userpass"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

**Message.java**

```
public class Message {

public static void mess(Context context,String string)
{
    Toast.makeText(context,string,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

Comment: `After clicking submit button, a massage arises`.  Ship that app!  Put it in the Play  Store, I'll buy it ;)

Comment: @Simon I guess it's an app for a SPA... ;)

Answer (score 2):

`et2` is null in your code:

```
et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userpass);
```

both line is `et1` you need change one of those to `et2`

you get an error on following method

```
public void method(View v)
{
    String name=et1.getText().toString();
    String pass=et2.getText().toString();  // et2 is null

    long id=rahulDatabaseHelper.insertData(name,pass);
    if (id<0)
        Message.mess(this,"UnSuccessFull");
    else
        Message.mess(this,"Row Inserted SuccessFully");

}
```

after fixing this issue read @Der Golem's answer,

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @shayan pourvatan,

Change this line

```
et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userpass);
```

to

```
et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userpass);
```

Then... None of these instructions will work:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE ="create table" +TABLE_NAME+ "("+UID+ "integer primary key autoincrement, "
            +NAME+ "VARCHAR(255)"+PASSWORD+"VARCHAR(255));";
private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME;
```

You need to add some spaces:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
    UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
    NAME + " VARCHAR(255)" + PASSWORD + " VARCHAR(255))";
private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever oncreate method of sqliteopenhelper class executed at that time it will create the table.
    but in your query string your are missed some spaces so that the table is not creating, so it is causing table not found error

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE ="create table" +TABLE_NAME+ "("+UID+ " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                +NAME+ " VARCHAR(255)"+PASSWORD+" VARCHAR(255));";
```